# How display message during redirecting instead of white page

Tags: javascript, redirect, gmail, message

How can i show a text message during redirecting (as gmail before home user) instead of white page ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the progress meter page? they arent actually doing a redirect, they are manipulating the DOM, showing the progress meter and then hiding it and showing the actual content after the their javascripts libraries have built it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display the message (using DOM/document.write(), etc), then have a wait (eg using window.setTimeout()) before actually doing the redirect

A simple example could be:

```
document.writeln("Redirecting you soon"); //Display message
setTimeout(function() {window.location.href="newpage.html"}, 5000); //Do redirect after 5 seconds
```

Alternative ways of doing this would depend on whether you are using any frameworks (Dojo, JQuery etc) and exactly how you want the message to be displayed.

Comment: Could you show me a simple example please ?